# C++ Unicode Encryption Library Required (Or is it?)

Tags: c++, unicode, encryption

I need to encryption several pieces of text in a file along side unencrypted text in the same file.  All the data is Unicode text.

In all the encryption libraries I have looked at Crypto++ Botan Etc... None of them "appear" to provide Unicode aware methods for encrypting / decrypting data E.G. data can be passed in/out using char, string instead of wchar wstring.   Does this matter? Just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Encryption libraries will use your data as a binary blob, not as characters. So it doesn't matter in what encoding the data is.

Encoding only affects **interpretation** of the data, not the data itself.

In other words: **It doesn't matter**

Answer (score 1):

Encryption works at byte level. It always requires binary blob as an input. So It does not matter in which encoding you are using to interpret data.